# How to substitute over multiple lines using sed

Tags: macos, sed

I'm trying to automatically replace a large code block.

I currently have it all on different lines as the format needs to be consistent.

I have tried both appending `\n` to the end of the lines and `\\n` to no avail.  Any tips?  Do you think I should just automatically replace the file from the repo or is this the better way to go about it?

EDIT:

```
 sed -i 'N' '''s_cat << EOF > DevServer_connection.json 
{ 
"name": "hlfv1", 
"x-type": "hlfv1",  
"x-commitTimeout": 300, 
"version": "1.0.0", 
"client": { 
    "organization": "Org1", 
    "connection": {  
        "timeout": {  
            "peer": { 
                "endorser": "300", 
                "eventHub": "300", 
                "eventReg": "300" 
            }, 
            "orderer": "300" 
        } 
    } 
}, 
"channels": { 
    "composerchannel": { 
        "orderers": [ 
            "orderer.example.com" 
        ], 
        "peers": { 
            "peer0.org1.example.com": {} 
        } 
    } 
},
```

It goes on for longer.  Remember that I have tried appending `\n` and `\\n` to the ends of the lines.

Comment: Can you post some of the code that you have tried?

Comment: @BrunoMazzardo Sure, It's pretty long and stack doesn't like that.  I'll post a snippet tho.

Comment: Maybe this help https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string

Comment: When you want to work across multiple lines, awk or perl would be better choices than sed.